# Imprimir un valor en un foreach y los que están relacionados a ese valor

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8

Estoy intentando generar un formulario dinámico en el imprima su sección y las preguntas que están relacionadas a ese sección
Por ejemplo

```
ANTECEDENTES PATOLÓGICOS
  teléfono:
  dirección:
  correo:
PARACLÍNICOS PREVIOS
  describa:
  grupo sanguineo:
  alergias:
```

algo de esta manera
este seria mi codio que utilizo en la vista

```
@foreach ($Secciones as $sec)
                                        <div class="row">
                                        <h2>{{$sec->secciones}}</h2>
                                        </div>
                                        
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-4 {{ $errors->has('nombre')  ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                                                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">{{$sec->preguntas}}</label>
                                                {!!Form::text('{{$sec->preguntas}}',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'{{$sec->preguntas}}'])!!}
                                                {!! $errors->first('nombre','<span class="text-danger">:message</span>')!!}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        
@endforeach
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y solo logro conseguir esto
si en una sección tiene mas de una pregunta la sección se repite ya estuve investigando pero no encuentro la solución alguien podría ayudarme se los agradecería mucho...
Lo estoy realizando con laravel 8.0
este seria mi controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Alertas_pacienteMpdel;
use App\Models\Secciones;
class vistapacienteController extends Controller

{
    public function obtenerSecciones(Request $request, $id_h){
     
        $Secciones=\DB::select("SELECT hp.`id_h`,hp.`id_historia`,h.`descripcion` AS historia_c ,s.`descripcion`AS secciones,p.`descripcion` AS preguntas
              FROM historiac_paciente AS hp
              INNER JOIN historia_clinica AS h ON h.`id_historia` = hp.`id_historia`
              INNER JOIN secciones AS s ON s.`id_historia` = h.`id_historia`
              INNER JOIN preguntas AS p ON p.`id_seccion` =  s.`id_seccion`
              WHERE hp.`id_h` = ?",[$request->id_h]);


        return view('paciente.detalle_paciente.historia_c.vista_paciente') 
        ->with('Secciones',$Secciones);
           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bueno puedes guardar los resultados en una arreglo y validar:

```
// creamos el areglo
@php
    $secc = array();
@endphp
@foreach ($Secciones as $sec)
    // validos que no exista
    // esto para imprimir solo 1 vez cada seccion 
    @if(!in_array($sec->secciones,$secc))
        <div class="row">
        <h2>{{$sec->secciones}}</h2>
        </div>
        // agregamos esa seccion a arreglo para no repetir
        @php
            array_push($secc,$sec->secciones);
        @endphp
    @endif

        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-4 {{ $errors->has('nombre')  ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">{{$sec->preguntas}}</label>
                {!!Form::text('{{$sec->preguntas}}',null,['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'{{$sec->preguntas}}'])!!}
                {!! $errors->first('nombre','<span class="text-danger">:message</span>')!!}
            </div>
        </div>
                                        
@endforeach
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda , me marca este error `htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, array given`

Comment: @YairCedilloJaramillo ya edite esta usando print por eso marcaba ese error

Comment: Disculpa por las molestias ya realice la modificación pero me sale este error `in_array(): Argument #2 ($haystack) must be of type array, string given`

Comment: ya correjido: el arreglo es el segundo parametro, es que lo estoy a haciendo mas que todo a memoria sin provar!

Comment: SI YA FUNCIONO , muchas muchas gracias en verdad me ayudaste bastante te lo agradezco